# How to get object properties from outside a function?

Tags: javascript

How do I get the value of name or age from outside the function?

```
function foo(){
    var person={
        name: "abc",
        company: "pqr",
        age: 25
    };
}
console.log(foo().person.name);
```

Comment: return `person`.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write a class.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You don't return anything from function, function will return `undefined` implicitly always.
You must return `person` explicitly (and removed property because I guess you intended `person` value as is):

```js
function foo(){
    var person = {
        name: "abc",
        company: "pqr",
        age: 25
    };
    return person;
}
console.log(foo().name);
```